# Feminist 'she' when the action is bad

Tags: grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

When the gender of the subject of a sentence is unknown, I sometimes use the feminist `she` rather than the more common singular `they`. Now I happen to feel that something is wrong when I use it as subject of a bad/negative action.

In a specific case, I wanted to refer to the OP in a Stackoverflow question. The OP made a stupid mistake; I didn't feel like writing

> `she` made a stupid mistake

and I went for

> `they` made a stupid mistake

(I wasn't that rude in a comment, I'm just exaggerating for the sake of this question).

Are my thoughts stupid?

**UPDATE**

my question was edited; `feminist` was turned into `feminine`. However, I meant `feminist`, since some feminists recommend replacing "gender-neutral he" with "gender-neutral she."

Comment: It may be "feminist" to use "she" as an indefinite pronoun everywhere except when the predicate describes something negative, but it's also pretty sexist.  I'd use either "he or she" or, if you can stomach it, "they".

Comment: Using _she_ in place of "he or she" or "she or he" or "they" isn't gender neutral; depending on your motivation, it might be described as "gender compensatory." But I wouldn't adopt the practice myself because I think that getting beyond gender when referring to generic or hypothetical human beings is a worthwhile goal—and one that true gender neutrality in pronoun choice serves far better than selective gender specificity does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The goal of this type of pushback is to *claim territory* by deliberately declaring any unknown entity is female, or should be addressed as *female-neutral* by default**.

The "gender balance" is not suppose to be within oneself, rather to counterbalance the damage done by erasing half the population with masculine neutral which was enforced as an unquestionable rule when I was in school (research shows the masculine-neutral "rule" came from *one source*, and singular-they has always existed in written English). **Even if you use feminine-neutral 100% of the time you will never "balance the scale" of institutional re-enforcement, therefore success is measured in visibility, not parity.**

You are wondering whether you should alter the rule when the sentence shows *negative* behavior. "This POTUS is an international joke. **He** is a stain on White America." OK, bad example but it proves there are logical exceptions to replacing every pronoun with "she".

**Since you are making a political 'action' by deliberately changing the pronoun, you get to decide when to make an exception.** The goal is to represent the missing-half of the population under *all* situations and professions, in defiance of convention. This includes negative behavior too.

However, when you censor you pass an opportunity, but you are not technically "losing ground". The invisible woman remains invisible. The imbalance remains status quo. A critic might claim that your selective censuring is putting women on a pedestal, but no – *inaction* is not misrepresentation, it's nothing.

**Pick your battles. Based on the goal of *visibility-not-parity* some opportunities will be more successful and some are just a waste of time.** A side issue is that misgendering becomes a provocation if the person is obviously male, so it's possible your feminine-neutral *action* rises from *representation* to *provoking a response*. That may be inevitable, but sticking around for a battle with someone you already don't respect is undoubtedly missed opportunities to seed other conversations with feminine-neutral.

Comment: What is your source for 'research shows the masculine-neutral "rule" came from one source, and singular-they has always existed in written English'? I don't think I believe either of those statements. Using "he" for someone of unknown gender dates back to Old English according to the OED so I doubt there was a rule prescribing that usage at that point in time. Also the OED has the earliest example of singular *they* only dating back to a1375. If need be I can link to the quotes for both of these.

Comment: @laurel One could find [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://academic.oup.com/slr/article-pdf/29/3/139/4678274/hmn015.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiN58LLquLeAhVS_qQKHTWmC_8QFjACegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3eMfLRTkhJEnZtUHS-kCg8) for masculine rule and [this](https://public.oed.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-singular-they/) for singular they history

Comment: @MarioTrucco I’m not sure what point you’re trying to make. The first source, which only applies to the language used in laws, says “writers such as” so that says to me that it wasn’t just one source. The other page has the quote I was referring to, which chronologically is closer in time to today than the earliest English writing.

Comment: @Laurel just suggesting what sources wetcircuit could have

Comment: @Laurel, the earliest written OLD English texts (not just runes or grave markers) date from around 1000CE. **Check your math** 1375 is NOT "closer to today" which is 2018.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use either "she" or "he" when referring to a *specific* person of an unknown gender, especially in a context where that person can see what you're saying. It doesn't matter if you're saying something positive or negative. That person has an actual gender, and you have approximately a 50% chance of guessing it wrong.

Using *they* is possible here. Using *he or she* is technically correct, but seems awkward to me, because it calls attention to the fact that you don't know the person's gender. I think the best option is simply to use a noun phrase:

> **The original poster** made a stupid mistake

---

The "feminist *she*" that you talk about is analogous and probably in response to an older use of the masculine pronoun *he* (and its inflected forms) as a generic, non-specific gender-neutral pronoun. I found the following typical examples in a paper "[The extinction of masculine generics](http://www.academia.edu/1597246/The_extinction_of_masculine_generics)" by Brian D. Earp:

- "When you meet your new doctor, be sure to tell **him** about your bad  back"
- "If a person loses **his** wallet, **he** should visit the lost-and-found"
- "Everyone should take **his** seat when the bell rings"

(Just replace the masculine pronouns with their feminine equivalents to get the "feminist *she*" version.) In fact, neither generic *he* nor generic *she* seems to be common nowadays compared to other options: the paper I linked has some discussion of their use vs. the use of gender-neutral alternatives such as *he/she*.

It's true that in some cases, like the first sentence above, it is used for unknown, but possibly specific people. But in the situation you mentioned, a comment where the OP can see what you're saying, I'd recommend that you avoid this wording. There's no way to tell if a bare "she" or "he" is meant to be gender-neutral or gendered, so either could be interpreted as making an assumption about the OP's gender.

Comment: ***(Just replace the masculine pronouns with their feminine equivalents to get the feminist version.) *** <--- Perhaps you'd like to revise that comment?

Comment: @Araucaria: how would you recommend that I revise it?

Comment: That would depend on what you're trying to say. I don't think a majority of feminists would regard using female pronouns there the 'feminist' version and male ones the non-feminist version per se though ...?

Comment: @Araucaria: I see. I didn't know what to call it that wouldn't be overly wordy, so I just followed the OP's usage.

Comment: As you say, the alternation between "he" and "she" is a 'feminist' (I'd just say non-sexist)  generic, non-specific gender-neutral pronoun. But it doesn't mean that if gendered pronouns are used that feminists are against using male or female ones in a given instance - it's just important hat they're shared around equally. I like your helpful post otherwise. Maybe using female pronouns would *demonstrate* a  gender -sensitive approach? (no idea what the jargon is ...)

Comment: @Araucaria: some feminists seem to argue that being 'feminist' simply means, and is necessary for, being 'non-sexist.' But in any case, I don't want to discuss political opinions too deeply. The OP seems to be referring to a practice of always using "she" in a generic sense, rather than using "she" and "he" with equal frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with *she* (or *he*)—it’s simply a grammatical feature of English that third-person pronouns have gender by default. If you want to be gender-neutral, singular *they* is acceptable.